# Laravel permission on same resource for multiple roles (Spatie)

Tags: laravel, permissions, resources, roles, laravel-permission

I need to grant access to users with different roles to actions of one resource.

I tried the following but no luck in web.php routes file:

- Route::resource('trampas', 'TrampaController')->middleware('role:Administrador|Supervisor'); //Access to all actions
- Route::resource('trampas', 'TrampaController')->middleware('role:Monitoreador|Coordinador')->only('index', 'show');

But when i declare the 2nd line the first in annulled.

Same thing happens when it's declared in the controller's construct method:

- $this->middleware('role:Administrador');
- $this->middleware('role:Coordinador')->only('index','show');

Last line permission prevails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Laravel 5.8 and Spatie v3

Comment: you probably can do this in the routes too; since routes are ordered, you can put the `only` on top. If you need 4 roles you'll need to add them as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Middleware must all pass before the request is processed. If you want `index` and `show` to pass one of the roles you need to explicitly put all roles in the parameters.

In your controller:

```
class TampaController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
          $this->middleware('role:Administrador|Supervisor');
          $this->middleware('role:Administrador|Supervisor|Monitoreador|Coordinador')->only('index', 'show');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get why this is working:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('role:Administrador|Supervisor')->except('index', 'show');
    $this->middleware('role:Administrador|Supervisor|Monitoreador|Coordinador');

}
```

when what it seems to do is the opposite of what i need.

I need the the roles Administrador and Supervisor can access all actions and roles Monitoreador y Coordinador can only access to index and show actions. But the way it works seems to declare that Administrador and Supervisor can access all except for index and show actions.

Why could this be happening?